# Wordpress how to change capabilities of a custom post type created by a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, wordpress-capabilities

I'm looking to edit a CPT (custom post type) that a plugin has generated within WordPress, but I'm unsure how to go about it properly. The plugin I'm using that has created the CPT is WPCargo. The name of the CPT is 'wpcargo_shipment'.

My reason for editing this post type is I need more granular control over the user permissions of this plugin. I'm looking to restrict access to all other parts of WP in the backend except for WPCargo's CPT.

I'm attempting to use the [Members Plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/members/) by [Memberpress](https://memberpress.com/) to control my user permissions. I've found this [article here](https://thinktandem.io/blog/2020/11/06/cpt-permissions-members-plugin/), which talks about tweaking a post type for the Members Plugin as it's being created but not after the fact.

Here's my attempt at editing the CPT, but my attempt appears somewhat work, but not entirely.

```
/* Edit (wpcargo_shipment) cpt */
function edit_wpcargo_shipment_capability( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'wpcargo_shipment' === $post_type ) {
        $args['slug'] = $slug; // get and store slug for later use.
        $slug_plural = $slug . 's'; // define slug as plural & store for later use.
        $args['map_meta_cap'] = true;
        $args['capability_type'] = $slug;
        $args['capabilities'] = [ // this is the part im most uncertain of.
            'create_posts' => 'create_' . $slug_plural,
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_' . $slug_plural,
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_' . $slug_plural,
            'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_' . $slug_plural,
            'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_' . $slug_plural,
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_' . $slug_plural,
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_' . $slug_plural,
            'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_private_' . $slug_plural,
            'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_' . $slug_plural,
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_' . $slug_plural,
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_' . $slug_plural,
            'read' => 'read',
        ];
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'edit_wpcargo_shipment_capability', 10, 2 );
```

**The Result:**

[image: Result in Members Plugin]

**Something I didn't expect to see and don't understand:**

[image: Result in Memebers Plugin]

**Question:**

it's been generated, and if you can (if I should), how do you do it?I want to know if it is possible to edit a CPT's args after

**Note:**

I thought about de-registering and re-registering the CPT from WPCargo myself but wanted to see if a more straightforward solution was possible first.

Comment: From what i understand you want to add/remove capabilities for specific role ? Check my answer here how to remove capabilities per user role - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376545/remove-move-to-trash-under-woocommerce-order-action-for-shop-manager/69376998#69376998

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track!

> *"I thought about de-registering and re-registering the CPT from WPCargo myself"*

**NO NEED** for de-registering and re-registering. It's absolutely feasible after you install and activate your plugin.

So here's what's happening, when "WPCargo" registers its custom post type, it uses "post" type as `capability_type`.

What does that mean? Well, it means `wpcargo_shipment` post type will inherit all of the default "post" type `capabilities`. This is the wordpress default behavior.

If you go to the following path:

> your website folder > wp-content > plugins > wpcargo > admin > classes

And open up `class-wpc-post-types.php` file, on line `43` you see `WPCargo` uses `'capability_type' => 'post'` argument to register its post type (i.e wpcargo_shipment). This will make `wpcargo_shipment` custom post type to inherit default "post" capabilities, which means, on the "members" plugin you have control over the "post" type capabilities. What happens to the "post" capabilities, will happen to the `wpcargo_shipment` custom post type too!

[image]

As you can see, there is no custom post type capability tab for "Shipment".

**BUT** you want to have a specific tab for your "Shipment" custom post type right?   We'll change it soon!

---

Well, there are two ways you could do that:

#### 1st way, recommended way

1. You could use `register_post_type_args` filter hook, to add a custom capability type which will have its own capabilities tab. The following code goes into your `functions.php` file of your theme.

```php
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'editing_wpcargo_shipment_capability', 10, 2);

function editing_wpcargo_shipment_capability($args, $post_type)
{
  if ('wpcargo_shipment' === $post_type) {
    $args['map_meta_cap'] = true;
    $args['capability_type'] = 'your_custom_type'; // You could set your capability type name here
  }
  return $args;
}
```

Which will give you a new capability type named "your_custom_type", Which will show up on your "members" plugin, which will give you all of the wordpress capabilities!

**Note:**

- Setting `map_meta_cap` to `TRUE` will do the magic here!
- I've used `your_custom_type` as your `capability_type`, just to give you an example, feel free to change it!

[image]

Now you have a separate tab for your custom post type capabilities! :-)

---

#### 2nd way, NOT recommended

You could navigate to the following path:

> your website folder > wp-content > plugins > wpcargo > admin > classes

And open up `class-wpc-post-types.php` file, on line `43`.

Replace:

```php
'capability_type' => 'post'
```

with:

```php
'capability_type' => 'your_custom_type',
'map_meta_cap'    => true,
```

Which will basically give you the same thing:

[image]

**Note:**

- The 2nd solution is not recommended, since we're manipulating that plugin core files. If you want to do it, then keep an eye on the future updates of the plugin and make sure your changes will stay intact!

---

Also worth mentioning, in both solutions "custom" tab will stay intact with NO extra stuff!

[image]

Comment: I must apologise for coming back to you so late. I've been a tad busy as of late. But I want to thank you for your detailed and most informative post. 

It's frustrating to know I was so close, just couldn't figure the best way to progress forward. That being said your answer has helped a bunch. Thanks again.

Comment: On a side note, after adding your 1st method, which I agree is the better way. I still get options appearing in the custom tab.

Comment: Additionally, even with `manage_options` set to `true`, the new `capability_type` cannot access the dashboard without having post-editing enabled. Any idea why this could be happening?